# How to browse an in memory sqlite database in python

Tags: python, sqlite, memory

I need to use an in memory sqlite database with the following constructor:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```

But in debugging, I find it very inconvenient because unlike file-based database, I cannot browse the database in the debugger.

Is there a way to browse this database on the fly?

Comment: What do you mean by browse? Do you mean running queries on it?

Comment: yeah, but on the fly, i.e. in debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write python scripts in debugger to perform any queries.
For example, consider the following program:

```
import pdb
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('create table abc (id int, sal int)')
cur.execute('insert into abc values(1,1)')
cur.execute('select * from abc')
data = cur.fetchone()
print (data)
pdb.set_trace()
x = "y"
```

Once we enter debugging (pdb), we can write queries like the following:

```
D:\Sandbox\misc>python pyd.py
(1, 1)
> d:\sandbox\misc\pyd.py(11)<module>()
-> x = "y"
(Pdb) cur.execute('insert into abc values(2,2)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02BB04E0>
(Pdb) cur.execute('insert into abc values(3,3)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02BB04E0>
(Pdb) cur.execute('select * from abc')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02BB04E0>
(Pdb) rows = cur.fetchall()
(Pdb) for row in rows:    print (row)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(Pdb)
```